# Magento 2.1 Shipping

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping

Having a carrier extending **AbstractCarrierOnline** and implementing **CarrierInterface**:
 What do the following methods supposed to do?

**requestToShipment**
**_doShipmentRequest**

And where from are they being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestToShipment` is used to generate `shipping label content` and `tracking number`.  To check reference you can see `DHL` shipping method which is online shipping method.

`vendor\magento\module-dhl\Model\Carrier.php`

```
   /**
     * Do request to shipment
     *
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipment\Request $request
     * @return array|\Magento\Framework\DataObject
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function requestToShipment($request)
    {
        $packages = $request->getPackages();
        if (!is_array($packages) || !$packages) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('No packages for request'));
        }
        $result = $this->_doShipmentRequest($request);

        $response = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'info' => [
                    [
                        'tracking_number' => $result->getTrackingNumber(),
                        'label_content' => $result->getShippingLabelContent(),
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );

        $request->setMasterTrackingId($result->getTrackingNumber());

        return $response;
    }
```

And it used in

`vendor\magento\module-shipping\Model\Shipping\LabelGenerator.php`

```
/**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment $shipment
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function create(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment $shipment, RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        $carrier = $this->carrierFactory->create($order->getShippingMethod(true)->getCarrierCode());
        if (!$carrier->isShippingLabelsAvailable()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Shipping labels is not available.'));
        }
        $shipment->setPackages($request->getParam('packages'));
        $response = $this->labelFactory->create()->requestToShipment($shipment); // from here it called
        if ($response->hasErrors()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($response->getErrors()));
        }
        if (!$response->hasInfo()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Response info is not exist.'));
        }
        $labelsContent = [];
        $trackingNumbers = [];
        $info = $response->getInfo();
        foreach ($info as $inf) {
            if (!empty($inf['tracking_number']) && !empty($inf['label_content'])) {
                $labelsContent[] = $inf['label_content'];
                $trackingNumbers[] = $inf['tracking_number'];
            }
        }
        $outputPdf = $this->combineLabelsPdf($labelsContent);
        $shipment->setShippingLabel($outputPdf->render());
        $carrierCode = $carrier->getCarrierCode();
        $carrierTitle = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'carriers/' . $carrierCode . '/title',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $shipment->getStoreId()
        );
        if (!empty($trackingNumbers)) {
            $this->addTrackingNumbersToShipment($shipment, $trackingNumbers, $carrierCode, $carrierTitle);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

And it supposed to call while generating shipment from backend

`vendor\magento\module-shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save.php`

`$this->labelGenerator->create($shipment, $this->_request);`

Line number `146`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it supposed to be called inside checkout process? In which step?

Comment: I have updated my answer , see my edit @Pro-Magento

Comment: I was testing what you wrote. That was all I was missing. Thank you my friend. Accepting now...

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps you :) @Pro-Magento